# Android split build - manual obb file download necessary?

Tags: unity, google-play

I have an apk built with Unity 5.0.1 that has over 50MB. Google Play does not accept files over 50MB so I have to make a Split Build as covered in the Unity manual:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-OBBsupport.html

Now it says that I need to download the obb file manually. On the other hand, elsewhere I read that all apps that are downloaded from the play store are already downloaded with the obb file. So which one is it? Do I have to use the [Google Play Obb Downloader](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/3189) or not? Where is the downloaded obb file stored in the filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, Google Play will download it for you, [but it can fail some times](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).

> On most devices, Google Play downloads the expansion file(s) at the same time it downloads the APK, so your application has everything it needs when the user opens it for the first time. In some cases, however, your application must download the files from Google Play when your application starts.

The OBB should usually be stored in `Android/obb/com.example.package`. See Google's documentation on the expansion file [storage location](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#StorageLocation). It should also be named in a [specific format](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Filename).

> For example, suppose your APK version is 314159 and your package name
>   is com.example.app. If you upload a main expansion file, the file is
>   renamed to:
>
> main.314159.com.example.app.obb

Unity has a [plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/3189) in the asset store that should help you get started with handling this case.

Comment: This plugin for OBB from unity store is unavailable and I cant find a solution. Please help.

Comment: Hey Saad, I'm not actively working on Unity with Android anymore but I've pinged the folks at Unity to find out what happened with the plug-in, and meanwhile perhaps you could try https://github.com/Over17/UnityOBBDownloader

Answer (score -1):

Ones if obb are downloaded successfully and later on deleted. Google play is tell you about the negative case ;)